# how to combine mysql to one sql querie

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me combine this code into one sql please.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM tblinvoices.date) as extractdate, SUM(tblinvoices.total) as autotal FROM tblclients LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.id = tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblclients.country='AU' AND tblinvoices.status = 'Paid' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m');";
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(tblinvoices.total) as total FROM tblclients LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.id = tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblclients.country!='AU' AND tblinvoices.status = 'Paid' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m');";
```

Comment: You have a different where `tblclients.country` statement's in these two queries. It can't be combined

Comment: thanks, guess i goto work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this,

```
    ;with t1 as (
      SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM tblinvoices.date) as extractdate, SUM(tblinvoices.total) as autotal,row_number() over (order by extractdate) rn FROM tblclients LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.id = tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblclients.country='AU' AND tblinvoices.status = 'Paid' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')),
    t2 as (  
      SELECT SUM(tblinvoices.total) as total,row_number() over (order by col3) rn FROM tblclients LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.id = tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblclients.country!='AU' AND tblinvoices.status = 'Paid' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
    )select extractdate,autotal,total,col4
    from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Oh wow, im not familiar enough with mysql to understand what that is. how would i add that to php to display

Comment: This is the single query you can use as normal i think.

Comment: 't1 as (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM tblinvoices.date) as extractdate, SUM(tbli' at line 1'